# How to get the Google Drive API v3 Samples to work in C#?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api

So I have copied the code from the Google Drive API .NET Quickstart (v3) [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet) and the code works perfectly, listing all the files on my Google Drive as expected.  However when I try and use the upload sample code found [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads) I cannot upload a locally stored image to my Drive and the `request.ResponseBody` returns `null`.  I have also added additional Drive scopes, but it didn't help.  Why won't the sample code for uploading files work?

My code is as follows:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace Google_Drive_REST_App
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                       DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata,
                       DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,
                       DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadataReadonly,
                       DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly,
                       DriveService.Scope.DriveScripts};
        static string ApplicationName = "Google Drive REST App";

        UserCredential credential;
        DriveService service;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            using (var stream =
                new System.IO.FileStream("credentials.json", System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
                // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Drive API service.
            service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            // Define parameters of request.
            FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
            listRequest.PageSize = 10;
            listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";

            // List files.
            IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute()
                .Files;
            Console.WriteLine("Files:");
            if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Name, file.Id);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No files found.");
            }
            Console.Read();

        }

        private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
            {
                Name = "photo.jpg"
            };
            FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
            using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream("E:/My Documents/Pictures/test_pic.jpg",
                                    System.IO.FileMode.Open))
            {
                request = service.Files.Create(
                    fileMetadata, stream, "image/jpeg");
                request.Fields = "id";
                request.Upload();
            }
            var file = request.ResponseBody;
            Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + file.Id);
        }
```

Comment: please edit your question and describe the issues you are hiving.

Comment: I thought I had described the issues I'm having?!  I have removed the unnecessary last paragraph if that's what you meant?

Comment: @DalmTo Thanks for your help BTW... maybe you could "spread the love for Google APIs" by giving some actual suggestions to solve the issue I raised?

Comment: I would be happy to help could you define can't upload.   is there an error? where is this running? how big is the file? what type of file is it.  I am sorry you are frustrated but there isn't enough information to understand the issue.

Comment: This might also help until I get to work tomorrow and can have a look at your response to my questions https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/media_upload

Comment: This is running on Visual Studio 2015 (as a WPF app). There is no error message until the last line of `btnUpload_Click` when there is a null object reference on the `file` object. But my file (a small .jpg image - less than 0.5mb) doesn't appear in my OneDrive folder.  Sorry about the frustration, I was tired and have been struggling to get this working for several days now, so I desperately needed expert help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested the following code and it works fine.  I hope it helps you.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var service = Oauth2Example.GetDriveService(@"C:\Users\linda\Documents\.credentials\NativeClient.json", "test",
                new[] {Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService.Scope.Drive});

            var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
            {
                Name = "flag.jpg"
            };

            FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
            using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\temp\flag.jpg", System.IO.FileMode.Open))
            {
                request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, stream, "image/jpeg");
                request.Fields = "id";
                request.Upload();
            }

            var file = request.ResponseBody;
            Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + file.Id);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

This is a link to the [Oauth2Example](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Drive%20API/v3/Oauth2Authentication.cs)

Comment: "FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload does not contain a definition for 'Execute'".

Comment: @DalmTo Would I be better off switching to v2 of the Google Drive API as there seem to be no working samples for v3?  Most documentation and advice also seems to be for v2.  I'm guessing `request.Execute()` only works on v2 for example?

Comment: Fine i felt bad so created a test version myself the only difference i can see is that your \ are wrong in your path maybe it cant find the file.    Mine works.

Comment: OK, I fixed the back slash and I copied your Oauth2 class.  I can now upload successfully.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Others having issues with Drive uploads should look into Exception from your upload, that will give you a better idea of the actual problem.

Sample code:

```
var progress = request.Upload();

if (progress.Exception != null)
{
   //Log execption, or break here to debug
   YourLoggingProvider.Log(progress.Exception.Message.ToString());
}
```

This is how I got to the bottom of my problem.